# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, ansible

My environment:

```
X@mbp 7 % docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.24
 Version:           20.10.17
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.11
 Git commit:        100c701
 Built:             Mon Jun  6 23:04:45 2022
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.10.0 (82025)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.17
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.11
  Git commit:       a89b842
  Built:            Mon Jun  6 23:01:23 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.6
  GitCommit:        10c12954828e7c7c9b6e0ea9b0c02b01407d3ae1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.2
  GitCommit:        v1.1.2-0-ga916309
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
X@mbp ~ % docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.6.1
X@mbp 7 %
```

I'm trying to run following ansible'playbook:

```
X@mbp 7 % cat elastic.yml 
- name: community.docker.docker_compose
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: state:present
      community.docker.docker_compose:
        project_src: "/opt/X/{{item}}"
        files: [ "docker-compose.yml" , "docker-compose.override.yml" ]
        state: present
      with_items:
        - kubefwd
        #- auditbeat
        - filebeat
        - kibana
        - logstash
        - metricbeat
        #- packetbeat%                                                                                                                                                                                  
X@mbp 7 %
```

and getting following error:

> Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`

```
X@mbp 7 % ansible-playbook elastic.yml
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [community.docker.docker_compose] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [state:present] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=kubefwd) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "kubefwd", "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/s5/d76h78tn0hq6w_tppbfkz9mc0000gn/T/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_4_yo5xd0/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 497, in <module>\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'\n"}
failed: [localhost] (item=filebeat) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "filebeat", "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/s5/d76h78tn0hq6w_tppbfkz9mc0000gn/T/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_awbyirse/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 497, in <module>\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'\n"}
failed: [localhost] (item=kibana) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "kibana", "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/s5/d76h78tn0hq6w_tppbfkz9mc0000gn/T/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_x460bn36/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 497, in <module>\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'\n"}
failed: [localhost] (item=logstash) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "logstash", "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/s5/d76h78tn0hq6w_tppbfkz9mc0000gn/T/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_k3uv1s2y/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 497, in <module>\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'\n"}
failed: [localhost] (item=metricbeat) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "metricbeat", "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/s5/d76h78tn0hq6w_tppbfkz9mc0000gn/T/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_a6j6gs6m/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 497, in <module>\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'\n"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

X@mbp 7 % pip install docker-compose
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'

and even though I installed docker-compose, I still get same error:

```
X@mbp 7 % pip install docker-compose
Requirement already satisfied: docker-compose in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.29.2)
Requirement already satisfied: docopt<1,>=0.6.1 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (0.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: distro<2,>=1.5.0 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: texttable<2,>=0.9.0 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (1.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client<1,>=0.32.0 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (0.59.0)
Requirement already satisfied: docker[ssh]>=5 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (5.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema<4,>=2.5.1 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.20.0 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dockerpty<1,>=0.4.1 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv<1,>=0.13.0 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (0.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML<6,>=3.10 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker-compose) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko>=2.4.2 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from docker[ssh]>=5->docker-compose) (2.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3.0 in /Users/X/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dockerpty<1,>=0.4.1->docker-compose) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema<4,>=2.5.1->docker-compose) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema<4,>=2.5.1->docker-compose) (0.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema<4,>=2.5.1->docker-compose) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.20.0->docker-compose) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.20.0->docker-compose) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.20.0->docker-compose) (2022.6.15)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.20.0->docker-compose) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from paramiko>=2.4.2->docker[ssh]>=5->docker-compose) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from paramiko>=2.4.2->docker[ssh]>=5->docker-compose) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.5 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from paramiko>=2.4.2->docker[ssh]>=5->docker-compose) (37.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko>=2.4.2->docker[ssh]>=5->docker-compose) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Users/X/.pyenv/versions/3.9-dev/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt>=3.1.3->paramiko>=2.4.2->docker[ssh]>=5->docker-compose) (2.21)
X@mbp 7 % ansible-playbook elastic.yml
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [community.docker.docker_compose] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [state:present] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item=kubefwd) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "kubefwd", "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/s5/d76h78tn0hq6w_tppbfkz9mc0000gn/T/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload_vku36wx9/ansible_community.docker.docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 497, in <module>\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'\n"}
```

...

Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: It's the same error [that it **always** is](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+ModuleNotFoundError): your `python` used by whatever rando copy of `pip` that was isn't the one in your `ansible_python_interpreter`

Comment: Rather than installing manually, add a [`pip` tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) to your playbook. This will target by default the `ansible_python_interpreter` install used on your target (localhost in thins case) and make sure the module is available in the correct python version.

Comment: thanks to each of you for the comments! as they're both likely to be true and using `ansible_python_interpreter` will probably work.. yet it feels more like "bandaid" solution, I do believe it's `pyenv` that causing this, and that's where I should be looking next..

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a `ansible_python_interpreter` variable to your task and point it to your python installation like this:

```
$ cat elastic.yml 
- name: community.docker.docker_compose
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: state:present
      community.docker.docker_compose:
        project_src: "/opt/X/{{item}}"
        files: [ "docker-compose.yml" , "docker-compose.override.yml" ]
        state: present
      vars:
        ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      with_items:
        - kubefwd
        #- auditbeat
        - filebeat
        - kibana
        - logstash
        - metricbeat
        #- packetbeat
```